# Contributing configuration of type "array" in VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating extension to VSCode that needs to be configured with array of objects containing fields: *a* and *b*. Using information available in extensions docs () it's unclear to me, if I can define [configuration](http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points) schema of array's elements, if I set property type to `"array"`. I tried to put following code in `"configuration"` contribution, but no success (I can retrieve successfully configuration in code, but there is no IDE hints when user fills in data):

```json
"title": "My config",
"properties": {
  "array_property": {
    "title": "Property",
    "type": "array",
    "properties": {
      "a": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "A a"
      },
      "b": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "A b"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried replacing `"type": "array"` with `"type": ["array", "object"]`, but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With a sample configuration like this

```json
"configuration": {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Test configuration",
    "properties": {
        "mytest.objarrconf": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "title": "inner objects",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "Name of inner object"
                    },
                    "size": {
                        "type": "number",
                        "description": "Size of inner object"
                    }
                }
            },
            "default": [],
            "description": "my test configurations"
        }
    }
}
```

it will result in this

[image]

Comment: is there documentation for this? what other types are available?

Comment: I'm also curious, please, tell us where this is documented.

Comment: Works for me. Great!

Comment: The configurations are defined using JSON Schema. See https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/index.html